# Running a batch at logon with Administrator Credentials to install Office C2R network installation

Tags: installation, group-policy, microsoft-office-2013

I'm trying to install Office 2013 C2R using GPO. The challenge here is CR2 requires administrator credentials at the same time its need execute `cmd.exe` with administrator privileges. I'm able to do the later, however it keeps on prompting me for administrator username and password . This is on client machine where in users logged in do not have administrative privileges.

Now this is what I want to accomplish:

1) Create a scheduled Task on GPO on domain to execute the batch file, bassically

```
runas.exe /user:domain\user -p Password@123 "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe " 

\\servernameoripaddress\folder\setup.exe /configure \\servernameoripaddress\folder\ndt.xml
```

This is something what I want to do however when I put this is in GPO under start up, it doesn't execute, however when I put it in logon it does execute but doesn't pick up the admin credentials and prompts for administrator user name and password.

I tried to change the UAC permissions following [this](http://www.petri.co.il/disable-uac-in-windows-7.htm) guide.

After doing this it prompts that you do not have administrator privileges and to contact the administrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RunAs doesn't support feeding it a password (there's many questions/answers on here regarding that).

You're trying to run the install in the user account's context, when it's unnecessary.

Just put `\servernameoripaddress\folder\setup.exe /configure \servernameoripaddress\folder\ndt.xml` in a batch file (no RunAs or anything) and then use the Computer Config -> Start up Scripts GPO to run it and have it installed by the 'System' account.

Microsoft provides documentation on doing what you are trying to accomplish:

[Deploy Office 2013 by using Group Policy computer startup scripts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602181(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: thanks techie007 it did help however it gives UNC command not supported I added REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /V DisableUNCCheck /T REG_DWORD /F /D 1

Comment: I would like to do this using GPO via Task Scheduler or a scheduled Task..I have tried under User Configuration control panel Task Scheduler ...though gpresult shows that it has fired the task but no installation done... any advice ...

Comment: @Farhim Why would you involve the Task Scheduler?

Comment: Well, there reason being i have to deploy it on around 200 systems n there is no way to trace on which systems they have been installed & it keeps on starting the installation on machines which its already installed... :(..